# Costs with CloudShare vs own development cloud?

Tags: development

Should we go for the own cloud or use CloudShare cost-wise?

Example scenario: we are going for long term SharePoint development with a growing team of both full time and part time + temporary developers. The cloud would become available for the temporary developers not having access to our dev computers. There should always be a dedicated sharepoint server per developer (sql and part of other infra would be shared). We have hardware infrastructure, hosting and licensing in place.

Answer (score 1):

Thomius,

CloudShare is a great approach for a long term SharePoint development environment even with full and part time + temporary developers.  From a Cost stand point, I would have to guess CloudShare would save you a ton of money and time.  CloudShare offers full infrastructure maintenance and allows each user to setup their environment based on what they need.  Additionally the CloudShare environment templates are hard to put a price on. These templates can help get a development environment up and going in no time at all. With CloudShare the hardware, hosting and licensing is all taken care of for you and there is no need to worry about setting up the servers and then installing the development applications along with installation of SharePoint.  We use CloudShare every day for our development, training and even product demos and it has saved us countless amounts of hours and thousands of dollars.  I would consider taking a deeper look into CloudShare and what it has to offer for your development needs and sign yourself up for a trail account.  I can assure you that you will think highly of their services.

Hopefully the info helps! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me first be transparent that I DO work for Skytap.

There are other solutions out there besides Cloudshare for SharePoint Development. Skytap has seen a lot of success with Enterprise organizations building out large SharePoint development environments. I recommend taking a look at both before making a decision on whether to pull it in-house or go with a provider. You can sign up for a trial with both organizations at no charge. Doing a head to head bake off will help in your decision making.

Best of luck.

- Nate